# Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Configuration must contain a "adapter" key

Tags: php, laminas

I have following error:

> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException:
> Configuration must contain a "adapter" key. in
> /var/www/test/vendor/laminas/laminas-cache/src/Service/StorageAdapterFactory.php:79

And this in my global.php:

```
    'caches' => [
    'FilesystemCache' => [
        'adapter' => [
            'name' => Filesystem::class,
            'options' => [
                // Store cached data in this directory.
                'cache_dir' => './data/cache',
                // Store cached data for 1 hour.
                'ttl' => 60 * 60 * 1
            ],
        ],
        'plugins' => [
            [
                'name' => 'serializer',
                'options' => [
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Same question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71949757/configuration-must-contain-a-adapter-key-in-laminas-framework

Comment: That isn't the solution for me. Keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In our set up we use different keyword, one to define the active cache and one for configuration:

```
return [
'active_cache' => 'cache_filesystem60',
'cache_configurations' => [
        'cache_filesystem60' => [
            'adapter' => [
                'name' => 'filesystem',
                'options' => [
                    'cache_dir' => getcwd() . '/data/cache',
                    'ttl' => 3600
                ],
            ],
            'plugins' => [
                'serializer'
            ]
        ],
    ]
];
```

With this configuration, you are able to define multiple cache targets and then choose the one that you want to use at runtime

Comment: I already solved it. Was a really hard cache problem.